# Need to design custom tabbar in swift 4 . - Update

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created the custom class for UITabBar, to design raised button and tabbar strip. Actually İ need to give wave background effect behind the raised button. İ have already created circle and raised button but setting not accurate not wave flow effect. İmage and code attached.

### Update:

I have attached my code for download and actual image(tabbar design I need included in assests).
Reference link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1evDPYdG2fGiMohWohJR2BQJNsKJHStQy/view?usp=sharing

```
func createPathCircle() -> CGPath {
    
            let radius: CGFloat = 40.0
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let centerWidth = self.frame.width / 2
    
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (centerWidth - radius * 2), y: 0))
            path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: centerWidth, y: 0), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(180).degreesToRadians, endAngle: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))
            path.close()
            return path.cgPath
        }
```

Actual what İ need to achieve
[image]

[need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBLbK.png)

Comment: @aunnnn Can you please guide me.

Comment: I have downloaded your project, so you want the button be in the right position?

Comment: @JohnHoang Yes but actually two issues, one is button placement issue for all the devices and second is background (which is tabbar circle) needs to set like wave up form.

Comment: @JohnHoang first part İ have done it, only second issue is left.

Answer (score 0):

- Hmm, you just fixed its position on ViewController.swift, button.frame
- Simple to decrease y-axis like this

```
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 32, y: self.view.bounds.height - 80, width: 64, height: 64)
```

Comment: Thank you but the issue is still persists, your mentioned setting works on İPhone 8 but as we change devices (İPhone XR, XS or İPhone 8 plus) button setting disturbed. How can İ set ıt for all views?

Comment: Finally i done it button position by using switch statement - UIScreen.nativebound
`if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 1920, 2208:
                print("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+")
case 1792:
                print("iPhone XR")
                button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 32, y: self.view.bounds.height - 114, width: 64, height: 64)`